# Include zero counts when grouping by multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have a table (TCAP) containing the gender (2 categories), race/ethnicity (3 categories), and height (integer in inches) for multiple individuals. For example:

```
GND     RCE      HGT
1           3           65
1           2           72
2           1           62
1           2           68
2           1           65
2           2           64
1           3           69
1           1           70
```

I want to get a count of the number of individuals in each possible gender and race/ethnicity combination. When I group by GND and RCE, however, it doesn't show zero counts. I've tried the following code:

```
SELECT
   GND,
   RCE,
   COUNT(*) TotalRecords
FROM TCAP
```

GROUP BY GND, RCE;

This gives me:

```
GND   RCE   TotalRecords
1         1         1
1         2         2
1         3         2
2         1         2
2         2         1
```

I want it to show all possible combinations though. In other words, even though there are no individuals with a gender of 1 and race/ethnicity of 3 in the table, I want that to display as a zero count. So, like this:

```
GND   RCE   TotalRecords
1         1         1
1         2         2
1         3         2
2         1         2
2         2         1
2         3         0
```

I've looked at the responses to similar questions, but they are based on a single group, resolved using an outer join with a table that has all possible values. Would I use a similar process here? Would I create a single table that has all 6 combinations of GND and RCE to join on? Is there another way to accomplish this, especially if the number of combinations increases (for example, 1 group with 5 values and 1 group with 10 values)?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `CROSS JOIN` make for `GND`,`RCE` columns then do `OUTER JOIN` base on it.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT t1.GND,t1.RCE,COUNT(t3.GND) TotalRecords
FROM (
    SELECT GND,RCE
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT GND
      FROM TCAP
    ) t1 CROSS JOIN
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT RCE FROM TCAP
    )  t2
) t1
LEFT JOIN TCAP t3 ON t3.GND = t1.GND and t3.RCE = t1.RCE
group by  t1.GND,t1.RCE;

| GND | RCE | TotalRecords |
| --- | --- | ------------ |
| 1   | 1   | 1            |
| 1   | 2   | 2            |
| 1   | 3   | 2            |
| 2   | 1   | 2            |
| 2   | 2   | 1            |
| 2   | 3   | 0            |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qvqigt7xfEGbqbpZjubkM7/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the results -- with a final `group by`:

```
select g.gnd, r.rce, count(t.gnd) as cnt
from (select distinct gnd from tcap) g cross join
     (select distinct rce from tcap) r left join
     tcap t
     on t.gnd = g.gnd and t.rce = r.rce
group by g.gnd, r.rce;
```